# Visual force page error

Tags: visualforce

I have two custom objects summary__c and acquistion_deal__c

Summary__c is look like contact object

acquistion_deal__c is look like account object
Both objects have lookup relationship between each other
I have created custom button called back button in summary__c object, if i click back button it should redirect to acquistion_deal__c object

> My controller class:

```
public with sharing class SummaryController{
 Public Summary__c  currentsummaryrecord{get; set;} 
 Public Acquisition_Deal__c  Aquistiondealrecord{get; set;}
public SummaryController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
 this.currentsummaryrecord = (Summary__c)controller.getrecord();

    }
 public PageReference back(){

            Aquistiondealrecord = [Select id from Acquisition_Deal__c  where id=:currentsummaryrecord.id];

            PageReference dealpage= New PageReference('/'+Aquistiondealrecord.id);
            return dealpage;
    }   
    }
```

> Vf page

```
 <apex:page standardController="Summary__c" extensions="SummaryController" action="{!back}">
    <apex:form >
    <apex:commandbutton value="Back" action="{!back}"/>
    </apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

Error:

> List has no rows for assignment to SObject Error is in expression
>   '{!back}' in component  in page to_redirect:
>   Class.SummaryController.back: line 10, column 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query:

```
select id
from Acquisition_Deal__c
where id = :currentsummaryrecord.id
```

will never return any rows because `currentsummaryrecord` is an instance of a `Summary__c` not of an `Acquisition_Deal__c`.

You may be intending something like this where the lookup field is used:

```
select id
from Acquisition_Deal__c
where id = :currentsummaryrecord.Acquisition_Deal__c
```